# Change part of links in .html files

Tags: string, bash, replace, sed, awk

I am currently in the process of migrating a mediawiki to sharepoint.

I've created a dump of the wiki pages and am now in the process of modifing the files for a seamless import into a sharepoint wiki.

The last problem remaining is that the address of the pages have changed, so the links in the .html files won't work anymore.

The links are currently in the following format:

```
../../../a/b/c/sitename.html
```

The format i want to get to is:

```
http://host/sites/site/wiki/sitename.aspx
```

I can replace the first part (`../../../a/b/c/`) with `sed`.

The problem I'm facing lies in the second part (`sitename.html`). I want to keep `sitename` but replace the `.html` extension with `.aspx`. The method used should be applicable to different sitenames so that I don't have to add an extra `sed` command for every sitename.

Comment: Are there other similar looking URLs such as `../../../a/b/c/not-a-sitename.html` where the `.html` suffix needs to be left untouched?

Answer (score 1):

One way with `awk`:

```
awk -F/ '/\.html/{sub(/\..*/,"",$NF); print "http://host/sites/site/wiki/"$NF".aspx"}' htmlfile
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this GNU sed,

```
echo "../../../a/b/c/whateversitename.html" | sed 's#\(../../../a/b/c/\)\(.*\)\.html#http://host/sites/site/wiki/\2.aspx#g'
```

Answer (score 1):

`sed` can work with multiple expressions, so if you are using one `sed`, you just add another expression to that, not another `sed`

```
[[bash_prompt$]]$ cat log
../../../a/b/c/sitename.html
[[bash_prompt$]]$ sed -e 's#../../../a/b/c#http://host/sites/site/wiki#g'  \
>  -e 's#html$#aspx#g' log
http://host/sites/site/wiki/sitename.aspx
```

Adding in a single expression

```
[[bash_prompt$]]$sed -e 's#../.*/\([^.]*\).html#http://host/sites/site/wiki/\1.aspx#g' log
http://host/sites/site/wiki/sitename.aspx
```